# The named parameter isn't defined:

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been having problems since the null safety update came. I searched a lot but couldn't find enough resources.

```
class AllCoins {
  String symbol;
  String iconUrl;
  double marketCap;
  double price;

  AllCoins(this.symbol, this.iconUrl, this.marketCap, this.price);
  factory AllCoins.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return AllCoins(
      symbol: json["symbol"],
      iconUrl: json["iconUrl"],
      marketCap: json["marketCap"],
      price: json["price"],
    );
  }
}

error: 4 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found. 
error: The named parameter 'symbol' isn't defined.
error: The named parameter 'iconUrl' isn't defined. 
error: The named parameter 'marketCap' isn't defined. 
error: The named parameter 'price' isn't defined.
```

Actually I just wanted to get data with null safety active but there is no helpful video. I'm still trying to learn flutter and dart but it gets harder as updates come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you're using **named arguments** where **positional arguments** are expected.

To use named parameters update the constructor by adding `{` `}` around the parameters

```dart
AllCoins({required this.symbol,required  this.iconUrl,required  this.marketCap, required this.price});
```

To continue using positional parameters, update `fromJson`:

```dart
factory AllCoins.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return AllCoins(
      json["symbol"],
      json["iconUrl"],
      json["marketCap"],
      json["price"],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks it works, do you know any doc or video where null safety is active?

Comment: A learning resource for flutter or dart where they are using null-safety to teach? Good question :) But Unfortunately I don't. As its been launched recently there isn't much available right now, the best I can share with you is
[Dart null safety in Action | Workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdKwuHQvArY)

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

For null safety use this code:

```
class AllCoins {
  
  String? symbol;
  String? iconUrl;
  double? marketCap;
  double? price;
  
  AllCoins({this.symbol,this.iconUrl,this.marketCap,this.price});


  factory AllCoins.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    return AllCoins(
      symbol: json["symbol"],
      iconUrl: json["iconUrl"],
      marketCap: json["marketCap"],
      price: json["price"],
    );
  }
}
```